# Subclass UIButton and detect UIControlEventTouchUpInside

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

i'm trying to detect when a button was pressed, so respond to the UIControlEventTouchUpInside event, i have tried this:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    if (highlighted)
    {
        self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.circleLayer setFillColor:self.color.CGColor];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.circleLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
        self.titleLabel.textColor = self.color;
    }
}
```

but it's only when there is the finger on the button and not released, how i can detect in the subclass the touchup inside action?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is add a target in your init method, and have a boolean to keep the button state :

in CustomButton.h

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL selected;
```

in CustomButton.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.selected = NO;
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(toggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}


- (IBAction)toggle:(id)sender{
    self.selected = !self.selected;
    if (self.selected)
    {
        self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.circleLayer setFillColor:self.color.CGColor];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.circleLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
        self.titleLabel.textColor = self.color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIControlEventTouchDown` instead of `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` so it's action method will call when your button will be down.